# Android Phonegap getting Unfortunately <app> has stopped

Tags: android, cordova

If I change the project build target in a Phonegap app I get "Unfortunately  has stopped unexpectedly"

I have made app with a target build path of 4.0.3 and set the min-sdk to 7.  The app will run fine at first but Google does not allow it to be downloaded by a tablet.

If I do anything to change the Build Target and/or change the build target to the original version after I get the same message.  The app will not load on any device at that point.

I am not sure what is causing this but even if I have an app has beeb installed fine and run fine, if I modify a file it gives me an error.

One more thing, I noticed that if I push the file to bitbucket it starts doing this also but not all the time.  Here is a error message that I received from the  play market.

Any help is appreciated.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{your.abSmallBusinessMarketing.hapmen/your.abSmallBusinessMarketing.hapmen.FlowChartbyHapmanActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: your.abSmallBusinessMarketing.hapmen.FlowChartbyHapmanActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/your.abSmallBusinessMarketing.hapmen-1.apk] at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: your.abSmallBusinessMarketing.hapmen.FlowChartbyHapmanActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/your.abSmallBusinessMarketing.hapmen-1.apk] at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)

Here is the maifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.abSmallBusinessMarketing.hapmen"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
         android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FlowChartByHapmanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Posting logcat was a good start - it suggests you may have a mismatch between the manifest and java, please post the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inconsistent capitalization of "by" in the activity name between java and the manifest.